# Doubts on making a secure login with a RESTful API

Tags: rest, session, ssl, xss

I'm building a web application that features a RESTful API, but I have some doubts.
**Yes, I have a SSL certificate** for my domain, would that be enough for sending POST (login, with username and password as a plain text, for example, as parameters) requests to my web application?
Another question: should I save a session-id on the client (localStorage) to make a sort of auto-login if the session is still available?
Should I save something else?
How do I *"auto-login"* with the session-id only?
**Note**: Every request (except /login) would be authenticated with the session-id.

Thank you in advance for replying.

Answer (score 0):

you can use basic authentication or oauth2.0 with an Authorization header containing a token for each request.
https://oauth.net/2/
https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/